# MS Sql and Hibernate entityManagerFactory with DAO's in Spring XD

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-xd

**Is it possible to use to use `MS Sql` and `Hibernate` entityManagerFactory with DAO's in Spring XD??**

I have a Configuration Class in my project in which I am writing Beans necessary for required configurations for my project like my `DataSource` and `JDBCTemplate` .

I also have Beans like

```
 @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("sqlServerDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
      lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
      lef.setPackagesToScan("de.id.dih");
      return lef;
  } 

private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
      hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
      return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf) {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf.getObject());
      return transactionManager;
  }
```

When I deploy my project in Spring XD,

I get Exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaVendorAdapter.
```

Then, I added the dependancy for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, I got exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
```

I tried to include dependancy for Spring Boot with and without Scope provided. I even tried adding dependancies for

```
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api, 
hibernate-entitymanager, 
spring-orm
```

to local POM.

I also moved the dependencies directly to Spring XD lib folder, and after doing that I got exception:

```
ERROR main boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set .
```

And when I set the hibernate.dialect my exception looks like:

**16:39:23,344 ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Exception deploying module
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener**
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:274)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:203)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:231)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployJobModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:530)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.onChildAdded(ContainerRegistrar.java:447)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.access$800(ContainerRegistrar.java:95)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$DeploymentListener.childEvent(ContainerRegistrar.java:826)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener is not assignable to interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:369)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:375)
    ... 29 more

Does any body have an idea of what might be causing this Exception ?

**HELP REGARDING WORKING EXAMPLE OF THE ABOVE WITH SPRING-XD IS GREATLY APPRECIATED.**

Thanks

Comment: `'hibernate.dialect' not set`-- have you tried setting the dialect property?

Comment: I have not even moved to the point of deploying the job in Spring XD , When I start my Spring XD in singlenode.I get this exception:

ERROR main boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: I have moved the libs  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-orm to Spring XD/lib